# AT1 ratio, Core T1 ration and CET1 ratio

Tags: basel, accounting, banking-regulations

I would like to first know the precise definition of each one of those 3 ratios as well as there differences. On the web there is bit of a mess on the explanations. I could not find a simple and clear systematic presentation of those 3 without mixing the terms and others synonyms. That let me even more lost.

Besides that it would be great if someone could explain me in a nutshell the main issues, context in which each regulatory ratio is inserted in and so there reason to exist.

Please be free to recommend me some reference lectures on the subject. Especially those for beginners on regulation subjects.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please look at the 16 December 2010 publication of the Basel III regulatory frameworks for capital and liquidity and the 13 January 2011 press release on the loss absorbency of capital at the point of non-viability and related FAQs "Basel III definition of capital - Frequently asked questions" like bcbs 211.